# Deuglify element-mutating Python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am looking for idioms to deuglify Python for loops which replace (as opposed to mutate) elements in the iterable which is being iterated. Specifically, consider the following four (for-) loops:

Loop A: a read-only Python loop written by a C programmer

```
for i in range(len(iterable)):
    print(iterable[i])
```

Loop B: a read-only Python loop wirtten by a Python programmer

```
for e in iterable:
    print(e)
```

Loop C: a failed attempt at writing an mutating Python loop written by an inexperienced Python programmer

```
for e in iterable:
    if condition(e):
        e = new_value(e)
```

Loop D: A fix of loop C which resorts to reverting to the ugly style of Loop A

```
for i in range(len(iterable)):
    if condition(iterable[i]):
        iterable[i] = new_value((iterable[i]))
```

Besides being abominably ugly, Loop D fails for non-sequence iterables.

I am looking for idioms and techniques which

- a) mitigate the ugliness of loop D
- b) allow a loop to modify the contents of non-sequence iterables (in the subset of cases where it makes sense)

Notes:

1. The original container should be *modified*; the point is NOT to create a new container.
2. I am *intimately* familiar with the reasons why Loop C fails: You really do not need to explain to me why it doesn't work. What I am looking for is better ways of writing Loop D.
3. I am not trying to modify the whole container in any of the loops, just some of its individual contained elements: you do not need to explain to me that modifying the whole container while looping over it, is a bad idea.
4. I am acutely aware that it is not possible to modify the elements of iterables in general. But it is possible in certain specific cases, and that is what part b) is about.

Comment: "allow a loop to modify the contents of **non-sequence iterables** ", i think iterables are the sequences and there is no **non-sequence iterables**.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay: I suspect that the OP would like a technique that generalises to allow iterating over dictionaries and other mappings that don't have simple integer indices.

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay Here are some examples of things that are iterable, but are not sequences: `open('/etc/passwd')`, `dict(a=7, b=3)`, `iter('hello')`, `def x(): yield 1` followed by `x()`, `itertools.cycle()` etc., etc. None of these examples are good candidates for modification in a loop; that would require more space than the comment allows. Though one might argue that something based around `dict(a=1, b=2).values()` is a candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I've come up with a protocol (calling it *the muteration protocol*) which is inspired by `enumerate` and allows such loops to be written in a way that is not all that ugly. A loop using the protocol would look like this:

```
for setit, e in muterate(iterable):
    if e%2:
        setit(1000*e)
```

Just like `enumerate`, `muterate` returns an iterable which produces pairs: `enumerate`'s index is replaced with a setter function, which accepts the new value with which it replaces the original value in the container. `muterate` will work for any type of iterable which implements a `muterate` method, just like `iter` works for any type which implements an appropriate `__iter__` method. This means that muterating loops can be written in *exacatly the same way* for any type which supports muteration.

Below is a proof-of-concept implementation. Can't say that I'm too extactic about it, but perhaps it's a step in the right direction.

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import chain

# The global muterate function which dispatches to the various
# implementations
def muterate(it):
    try:
        return muterate.builtins[type(it)](it)
    except KeyError:
        try:
            return it.muterate()
        except AttributeError:
            raise TypeError('No muterator available for {}'.format(type(it)))
muterate.builtins = {}

# As I can't implement the muterate method on the builtins, these have
# to be installed externally in some place where muterate can find
# them
def make_muterator(get_iterator):
    def muterator(container):
        def make_setter(locator):
            def setter(new_value):
                container[locator] = new_value
            return setter
        for locator, value in get_iterator(container):
            yield make_setter(locator), value
    return muterator
muterate.builtins[list] = make_muterator(enumerate)
muterate.builtins[dict] = make_muterator(dict.items)

# An iterable, mutable type which does not (AND SHOULD NOT) support
# item setting.
def make_linked_list(data):
    the_list = EmptyList()
    for datum in data:
        the_list = LinkedList(datum, the_list)
    return the_list

class EmptyList:

    def __iter__(self):
        return; yield

    def muterate(self):
        return; yield

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self, head, tail):
        self._head = head
        self._tail = tail

    def __iter__(self):
        return chain((self._head,), self._tail)

    def muterate(self):
        def setter(new_value):
            self._head = new_value
        return chain(((setter, self._head),), self._tail.muterate())

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{}>".format(', '.join(map(str,tuple(self))))
    __str__ = __repr__

# Putting the muterate protocol through its paces
l = range(10)
d = {letter:rank for (rank, letter) in enumerate('abcdefghij')}
ll = make_linked_list(reversed(range(10)))
for iterable in (l,d,ll):
    for setit, e in muterate(iterable):
        if e%2:
            setit(1000*e)
    print iterable
```

Which gives the output:

```
[0, 1000, 2, 3000, 4, 5000, 6, 7000, 8, 9000]
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1000, 'e': 4, 'd': 3000, 'g': 6, 'f': 5000, 'i': 8, 'h': 7000, 'j': 9000}
<0, 1000, 2, 3000, 4, 5000, 6, 7000, 8, 9000>
```

In other words, all the odd elements have been multiplied by 1000 *inside the original container* by the muterating loop, which looks *identical* for all the types involved, isn't too ugly, and does not rely on the availability of item-setting.